# Python IDLE 3.7.4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, python-3.7

I downloaded Qt Designer for windows and when I run my app , this error appears :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adham\OneDrive\Desktop\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

and this my app :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType('First App.ui')

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Button.clicked.connect(self.get_result)
    def get_result(self):
        Name=self.ui.NameEdit.value()
        Password = self.ui.PasswordEdit.value()
        self.ui.Result.setText("Name: " + Name + "\n" + "Pass: " + Password)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The instructor uses python idle 3.5 and mine is 3.7.4 , how to make the designing app compatible with my version ?

Comment: Do you have PyQt5 installed?

Comment: Qt Designer is not the same thing as PyQt5.

Comment: No , How can I install PyQt5? 

Comment: @eyllanesc
I used this code on my cmd , I'm running Windows 10 but nth happened

"python -pip install PyQt5"

Comment: @user10987432 
got it 

Answer (score 0):

`python -m pip install` PyQt5 should work

Or you can try unistalling PyQt5 and use `python3 -m pip install *.whl`

Comment: it didn't work , what should I do?

Comment: I tried python idle 3.5 and same error appears